# How do I change the language from German to English in Eric7 Python ide?

Tags: python, ide

No idea how I did it but I managed to change the language to German. Now I can't change it back because Ich spreche nicht Deutsch. The documentation says the language can be changed in the preferences, but I have not been able to find anything that looks like language selection in the preferences.
All help gratefully received.
:-\